# what is source of story about healer sent by persian king to aravia and no one paid attention to him?

Tags: hadith, history, seerah

i wanted to ask "is there a hadith admonishing to not eat until being hungry?" and i have found [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50513/hadith-i-dont-eat-until-im-hungry) question in "similar questions" block. the answer to that question is enough for me.

i wanted to quote a text in my question. since i prepared to write my question, translated the text, using google, i make a new question, though i am not very interested to know out answer to it.

in book "kitab at-tarbiya" in tatar language, qayum nasiri writes:

> TWENTY-FIRST UPBRINGING One of the kings of Gajam sent a skilled
> doctor to the service of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be
> upon him). He lived in Arab countries for many years. No one came up
> to him, saying, "Heal me." One day he came to the Prophet (peace and
> blessings of Allaah be upon him) and complained. "I've been here for
> days, and no one has paid attention to me," he said. The Prophet
> (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The custom of this
> people is that they will not eat anything until they want to eat it,
> and they will start to refuse from food before they are full, that is,
> they will not eat until they are satiated.” The doctor said, "If
> that's the way to heal," then kissed the ground and left. Now, son,
> has this story sufficed for your upbringing? Don't eat your stomach
> full, you'll be in health, be satisfied with little.

the russian version of it says this way:

> It is known that one of the Persian kings once sent his best healer to
> Arabia to serve the prophet.

do you know what is source of this story?

i read this book in paper form in past. now, i used https://nsportal.ru/shkola/rodnoy-yazyk-i-literatura/library/2020/02/02/k-nasyyri-trbiya-kitaby where is also russian translation of it.

Comment: I guess you are referring to [Hadith I don't eat until I'm hungry](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50513/hadith-i-dont-eat-until-im-hungry/50571#50571)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a source of narration for this story. It is a story and anecdote that has been narrated in one of the old Iranian books called Golestan Saadi and it has more of a fictional aspect than a documentary.
And, of course, the original anecdote states that the non-Arab king sent this doctor to the Prophet. That is, it is not said that he was a Persian king.

https://hawzah.net/fa/LifeStyle/View/51357/%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AA%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%85-%D9%85%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%86%D9%87-%D9%88-%D8%AF%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%B1-%D8%A8%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C

Comment: do you know what is "Gajam"?